# gulp markdown to separate renderers and destinations

Tags: gulp

I'm attempting to take an input markdown file, run it through 2 different renderers, and save the output to different folders. My plan is to use blockquotes to keep specific content from rendering in one of the outputs. Here's my gulp file:

```
var gulp     = require('gulp'),
    marked   = require('marked'),
    markdown = require('gulp-markdown'),
    cache    = require('gulp-cached'),
    lazypipe = require('lazypipe'),
    merge    = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('markdown', function () {

    // setup mlive
    var mlive_renderer = new marked.Renderer();
    mlive_renderer.blockquote = function (quote) {
        return quote;
    };

    var mliveTasks = lazypipe()
        .pipe(markdown, {
            renderer: mlive_renderer
        });


    // setup hudsonvilleathletics
    var hudsonvilleathleics_renderer = new marked.Renderer();
    hudsonvilleathleics_renderer.blockquote = function(){ return ''; };

    var hudsonvilleathleticsTasks = lazypipe()
        .pipe(markdown, {
            renderer: hudsonvilleathleics_renderer
        });



    // create out pipe of src content
    var sources = gulp.src('src/**/*.md')
        .pipe(cache('markdown'));


    var mlive = sources
        .pipe(mliveTasks())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('mlive'));


    var hudsonvilleathletics = sources
        .pipe(hudsonvilleathleticsTasks())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('hudsonvilleathletics'));



    return merge(mlive, hudsonvilleathletics);

});
```

Running this completes without errors, but both contents are identical, and have additional `p` tags wrapped around headings. If I comment out one and just return the other it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

input file:

```
## This is a heading

> This is mlive only stuff

Here's some other stuff for both.

> one more for mlive
```

and the output (identical for both)

```
<p><h2 id="this-is-a-heading">This is a heading</h2></p>
<p>This is mlive only stuff</p>
<p>Here&#39;s some other stuff for both.</p>
<p>one more for mlive</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more digging I stumbled upon `gulp-mirror` and have managed to get this working. Using that I was able to move the destination calls to the lazypipes, and then mirror the sources to them. Here's the new gulpfile (with an additional tweak to remove ids from headings)

```
var gulp     = require('gulp'),
    marked   = require('marked'),
    markdown = require('gulp-markdown'),
    cache    = require('gulp-cached'),
    lazypipe = require('lazypipe'),
    mirror   = require('gulp-mirror');

gulp.task('markdown', function () {

    // start of by removing the id's for headings
    var heading = function (text, level) {
        return '<h' + level + '>' + text + '</h' + level + '>\n';
    };

    /*
     *  mLive Setup
     *
     *  convert any block quotes back to regular old p tags and save in the mlive folder
    */
    var mliveRenderer = new marked.Renderer();
    mliveRenderer.heading = heading;
    mliveRenderer.blockquote = function(quote){
        return quote;
    };

    var mliveTasks = lazypipe()
        .pipe(markdown, {
            renderer: mliveRenderer
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest, 'mlive/');


    /*
    *   HudsonvilleAthletics Setup
    *
    *   completely remove anything in block quotes and save to the other folder
    */
    var hudsonvilleathleticsRenderer = new marked.Renderer();
    hudsonvilleathleticsRenderer.heading = heading;
    hudsonvilleathleticsRenderer.blockquote = function(){
        return '';
    };

    var hudsonvilleathleticsTasks = lazypipe()
        .pipe(markdown, {
            renderer: hudsonvilleathleticsRenderer
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest, 'hudsonvilleathletics/');


    /*
    *   Finally run everything
    */
    return sources = gulp.src('src/**/*.md')
        .pipe(cache('markdown'))
        .pipe(mirror(
            mliveTasks(),
            hudsonvilleathleticsTasks()
        ));
});
```